# Why are the values of vector<int> inside initializer_list changing after calling the constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, initializer-list

I'm new to C++ and trying to setup a matrix class. The matrix is created from an `initializer_list` containing `vector<int>` entries as the rows of the matrix. 
One of the methods of this class should be `get_row(size_t rownumber)`. When I call the implemented method from the constructor, it returns the correct result. But when calling the same method from `main()`, the first two elements of each row contain some huge numbers that shouldn't be in there.

I assume the problem is somehow related to pointers. Though, I can't really find where the elements of the matrix could be overwritten between the call inside the constructor and the call inside main. When I went into debug mode in Eclipse the pointers seemed to point to the expected addresses ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> class myMatrix {
    private:
        initializer_list<vector<int>>::iterator it;
        initializer_list<vector<int>> matrix;
    public:
        myMatrix(initializer_list<T> values) {
        matrix = values;

        vector<int> chosen_row = get_row(1);
        cout << "Called from constructor: ";
        for (unsigned i = 0; i != chosen_row.size(); i++) {
            cout << chosen_row.at(i) << " ";
        }
        }
    vector<int> get_row(size_t x) {
        it = matrix.begin() + x - 1;
        return (*it);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    myMatrix<vector<int>> test{{3, 4, 5, 2}, {7, 2, 3, 4}};
    vector<int> chosen_row = test.get_row(1);
    cout << endl << "Called from main: ";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != chosen_row.size(); i++) {
        cout << chosen_row.at(i)<< " " ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Output is the following:

```
Called from constructor: 3 4 5 2 
Called from main: 187072144 22084 5 2
```

Can someone please tell me, where the error happens? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it seems `std::initializer_list` is not intended for prolonged storage of objects. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) states that no guarantees can be made about the objects stored in initializer_list after the oriinal one died, for perfomance reasons. Don't use `std::initializer_list` for storing stuff, only for initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`initializer_list` is a lightweight view over a `const` array that doesn't own (or extend the lifetime of) any of its elements.

When you write `{{3, 4, 5, 2}, {7, 2, 3, 4}}`, you're creating a temporary array of vectors on the stack - the `initializer_list` is basically a pointer+length view into it. After your matrix has been constructed, that array is destroyed.

Use a container such as `vector` instead of `initializer_list` inside your `matrix` implementation to solve the issue. E.g.

```
private:
    vector<vector<int>>::iterator it;
    vector<vector<int>> matrix;
```